# Fetching X-Mailer in java imap

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

How to fetch x-mail in java imap ?
I have written a sample program but it not working fine. 
I am getting null value. 
Where I am going wrong ?

```
import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder;
    import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage;
    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.internet.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.lang.reflect.Field;


/**
 *
 * @author vivek
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties props = System.getProperties();    
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993");
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
      Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
      store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "username", "password");
      System.out.println(store);
      Folder inbox =  store.getFolder("Inbox");
      inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);      
      FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();     
      fp.add("X-Mailer"");
      Message[] messages=inbox.getMessages(1, 2);      
      inbox.fetch(messages, fp);            
      for (Message message : messages) {
        System.out.println(message);        
        System.out.println(message.getHeader("X-Mailer""));

      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }

  }
}
```

Debug trace for imap is

```
 `DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.4
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 116.202.153.186 bs33if4292090ibb.10
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA XLIST CHILDREN XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! bs33if4292090ibb.10
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=username, password=<non-null>
A1 LOGIN username password
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE
A1 OK username@gmail.com vivek goel authenticated (Success)
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE
A2 OK Success
imaps://username@imap.gmail.com
DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
A3 EXAMINE Inbox
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()]
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 2]
* 27512 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 58271]
A3 OK [READ-ONLY] Inbox selected. (Success)
A4 FETCH 1 (BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (X-Mailer)])
* 1 FETCH (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (X-Mailer)] {4}


)
A4 OK Success
com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage@6ba7508a
null`
```

Comment: use `-Dmail.debug=true` to understand what is going on with the IMAP server. And X- headers are all optional.

Comment: I can't see X-Mailer Fetch . when i enable debug mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks ok, ish. Now, did you imap with say Thunderbird and CHECK if the X-mailer header even exists?

Comment: yes. it exist . but when I enable debug or iterate threw all header . i can't see this header. 
it is neither in fetch command.